# How to add multiple fields in columns of Power BI matrix and view them without drilldown

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I've trying out Power BI to solve some visualization problem in my organization and I've been working on desktop version of Power BI to try out its features.
I'm stuck at few issues and cannot find our way out of this.This is a sample view I've been trying to create:

Figure 1:
[image: 1]
We've a dataset containing Product Opinion across gender, Age Group, Geography etc. and we want to pivot the opinion across different parameters as shown above.But when we use Matrix view of Power BI and add two parameters in columns, it creates a drill down view as shown below:

Figure 2:
[image: 2]
On adding multiple fields in the column section we get an option to move down to next hierarchy as shown below:

Figure 3:
[image: 3]
Although we have the option to move down to hierarchy ,we are unable to show then side by side as we've shown in Figure 1.
Is there a way we can get the visualization as given in Figure 1 ?

Also, Currently the columns and rows are automatically sorted alphabetically. Is there a way we can adjust the column and row position as per our needs?

Comment: Siddhartha, did you find a solution for this because i'm having a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

To sort the rows in a custom order, you will have to create an index table. The below link walks you through the steps involved:

http://www.excelnaccess.com/custom-sorting-in-power-bi/

Now, to achieve the visualization you are looking for, the only way I can think of is to create two matrix visualizations (One for gender and other for age group) and place them in such a way, that it gives the illusion of the same table. There might be a better way to do this, but I these workarounds work just fine. Hope this helps.